# g++ no file generated

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, cygwin

So my problem is that when I try to compile my file using g++, I am not getting an output file. I am using Cygwinx64 on Windows 8. Also this command was working a week before so this is very strange. I have tried reinstalling the cygwin package of g++ but no luck.

TL;DR When I try to compile using g++ on cygwin, nothing happens

```
$ ls       
traverse.cc // this is a simple hello world program

$ g++ -o hello traverse.cc

$ ls            
traverse.cc // no file is generated...
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I can access g++ it just doesn't work

```
$ g++ -v          
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++           
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/lto-wrapper.exe          
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-4.8.3-3.x86_64/src/gcc-4.8.3/configure 
--srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-4.8.3-3.x86_64/src/gcc-4.8.3 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr 
--bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --datadir=/usr/share 
--localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib --datarootdir=/usr/share 
--docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin 
--host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix 
--without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc
--enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit 
--with-dwarf2 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ 
--enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm 
--enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada 
--enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar
 --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix
 --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id         
Thread model: posix          
gcc version 4.8.3 (GCC)
```

Also the folder path I am using does not contain spaces: `/cygdrive/h/users/jesse/workspace/hello_world/src`.

Comment: According to the output of `$ ls traverse.cc` (or, more correctly, the lack of output), you don't have a `traverse.cc`. You should be getting a compiler error.

Comment: Sorry updated question for format. traverse.cc is the output of ls. They just didn't output correctly when I asked the question @jww

Comment: Well now I'm just using another instance of minGW g++ which is outside of cygwin. This works but if someone can find a solution to the cygwin g++ I would be a happy person. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you expect to see when you execute

```
ls traverse.cc
```

When you execute that command, you should just see

```
traverse.cc
```

If the following command

```
g++ -o hello traverse.cc
```

produces no errors, you will see a file `hello.exe` under cygwin. Try

```
ls hello.exe
```

or, simply

```
ls
```

You should see `hello.exe` in the output.

Comment: Sorry the formatting was wrong. I just updated it. traverse.cc is the output of ls. @R Sahu